# Extract 2 prices from a string with a dollar sign using REGEXP_EXTRACT in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I'm struggling with extracting 2 float numbers from a string using REGEXP_EXTRACT in Hive. I only want the float numbers and no `$` sign.

Input String: `value=$110.60-$79.30,`

Expected outcome: `110.60` and `79.30`

I tried all of these variables, but the result was empty.

```
(str,'value=$$([0-9]* \ .[0-9]*)\ -$$([0-9]* \ .[0-9]*)', 1)

(str,'value=\$([0-9]* \ .[0-9]*)\ -\$([0-9]* \ .[0-9]*)', 1) 

(str,'value=(. * ?)-(. * ?)', 2)
```

If I make a lengthy sub-query and use `SUBSTR`, I can get rid of the `$` sign, but still doesn't return the 2nd value (`$79.30`).

**QUESTION**

What RegEx will achieve my desired output from this input?

Comment: Try sth like `$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`

Comment: Thanks! But it still returns empty  .. ;`-(

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_EXTRACT('value=$110.60-$79.30,',
      'value=(.*?)-(.*?)', 1)), '\$', '') returns $110.60 and the dollar sign doesn't go away.. Also when I choose 2, it returns empty.. :(

Comment: That's because you include `$` sign inside the match and then you use a lazy repetition `*?` that takes as little as possible. See eamples in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should help

```
regexp_extract(string `[$]([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)-$([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)`, 1)
regexp_extract(string `[$]([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)-$([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)`, 2)
```

It matches a number followed with dollar sign and keeps the number inside the first capturing group that is referenced with 1. Then you can take another match using 2.

> `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`
>
> Returns the string extracted using the pattern. For example, `regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2)` returns `'bar.'` Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using `'\s'` as the second argument will match the letter s; `'\\s'` is necessary to match whitespace, etc. **The `'index'` parameter is the Java regex Matcher group() method index**. See [docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more information on the 'index' or Java regex group() method.

[Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: Thanks for your help! They both returned empty... REGEXP_EXTRACT('value=$110.60-$79.30,', '$([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)', 1) AS test_a, 
REGEXP_EXTRACT('value=$110.60-$79.30,','$([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)', 2)  AS test_b

Comment: Dumb me, I forgot to escape `$` sign. try now

Comment: REGEXP_EXTRACT('value=$110.60-$79.30,', '[$]([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)-[$]([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)', 1) AS test_a,
REGEXP_EXTRACT('value=$110.60-$79.30,','[$]([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)-[$]([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)', 2)  AS test_b

Comment: THIS WORKED!! :D THANK YOU SO MUCH!